# How do I write a Makefile target for hundreds of numbered files?

Tags: makefile, globbing

I have some art projects that use blender as part of the toolchain.  I would like to be able to write a Makefile target which specifies that several hundred files can be updated with a single command.  The following syntax does not actually work, but expresses what I want

```
$(PNGS)/1/{0001..0720}.png: cube.blend
    blender -b  $< -S "Scene" -a
```

How do I do this in a Makefile?

I currently work around the problem by using `include blender.d` where blender.d is a generated file full of hundreds of lines like:

```
PNGs1 = /var/tmp/blender/hex-spinning/0001.png\
         /var/tmp/blender/hex-spinning/0002.png\
         /var/tmp/blender/hex-spinning/0003.png\
...
         /var/tmp/blender/hex-spinning/0450.png\
```

which is pretty brutal and inelegant.